# How can I locally detect time cheat in my windows phone 8 app?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Is it possible to check if as user has set the time settings as "set automatically" ? We need to use the app in offline mode, so the solution must not involve network communication.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is a global setting that can be viewed or modified by an app.

Comment: I agree. Definitely no way to modify it. Even if there is a way to read it, I would recommend against relying on it as it is no guarantee that there won't be time cheating. If the app has to work offline, there is simply no way to ensure system time is real and not tampered with.

Comment: In addition to there not being an API, even if there was, if the device is offline it has nowhere to sync from. So the user could manually set the time and then enable "automatic" syncing... which would do nothing.