# Windows Phone 8, programmatically check if set date and time automatically is On or Off

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a function in Windows Phone 8.1 to read if "Set date and time automaticaly " is ON?

Comment: wondering what you can do with such information

Comment: I have to store some info with a timestamp. When airplane mode is active or no internet connection is allowed,  i want verify if user has manipulated timestamp. I received some file with info with timestamp not sequential

Comment: what about if 1. the user uncheck the auto date set 2. change date 3. goes airplace 4. recheck the setting ? ==> you will have a date delta AND the date auto update checked

Comment: If you un uncheck auto date set, change date and recheck the setting, phone restore the original value. I can prevent insert data if auto date is off.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I locally detect time cheat in my windows phone 8 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644577/how-can-i-locally-detect-time-cheat-in-my-windows-phone-8-app)

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer you are looking for, but read on.

Sounds like you know they've manipulated it.  Your app needs some type of log keeping track of the highest time stamp.  It could even be just a single stored value.

When any action is taken, check the device's time against that stored stamp.  If the device time is prior to it, then you know they are manipulating the time and can make a decision on what to do at that point.

Should be trivial to implement.

Answer (score 1):

There is no global setting that can be viewed or modified by an app, that can check if the "Set date and time automaticaly" is on.